# dpkg postinst mkdir -p /var/{cache, run, doc} doesn't work as excepted

Tags: mkdir, dpkg, post-install

I am running following command in postinst script of custom dpkg package

> mkdir -p /var/{cache,run,doc}

The command works but create single dir named /var/{cache,run,doc} not three seperate dirs in /var .

Is there any alternative to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you have declared that the maintainer script is a `POSIX` shell script with `#!/bin/sh` instead of a `bash` script with `#!/bin/bash`. The `{}` syntax is a bashism.

You either need to use `bash`, or spell each directory explicitly like:

```
mkdir -p /var/cache /var/run /var/doc
```

What I'm wondering though is why you need those, because at least on Debian and derivatives these directories (except /var/doc which is known as /usr/share/doc) are already provided by `base-files`.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p /var/ cache run doc
```

Should do the job